# Large Powers without using Big Integer

Tags: java

I had a problem where i had to calculate sum of large powers of numbers in an array and return the result.For example arr=[10,12,34,56] then output should be
10^1+12^2+34^3+56^4.Here the output could be very large so we were asked to take a mod of 10^10+11 on the output and then return it.I did it easily in python but in java initially i used BigInteger and got tle for half the test cases so i thought of using Long and then calculating power using modular exponential but then i got the wrong output to be precise all in negative as it obviously exceeded the limit.

Here is my code using Long and Modular exponential.

```
static long power(long x, long y, long p)
{
    long res = 1;      // Initialize result

    x = x % p;  // Update x if it is more than or 
                // equal to p

    while (y > 0)
    {
        // If y is odd, multiply x with result
        if ((y & 1)==1)
            res = (res*x) % p;

        // y must be even now
        y = y>>1; // y = y/2
        x = (x*x) % p;  
    }
    return res;
}

static long solve(int[] a) {
    // Write your code here
    Long[] arr = new Long[a.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = setBits(new Long(a[i]));
    }
    Long Mod = new Long("10000000011");
    Long c = new Long(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        c += power(arr[i], new Long(i + 1),Mod) % Mod;
    }

    return c % Mod;
}

static long setBits(Long a) {
    Long count = new Long(0);
    while (a > 0) {
        a &= (a - 1);
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Then i also tried Binary Exponentiation but nothing worked for me.How do i achieve this without using big integer and as easily as i got it in python

Comment: And how exactly did BigInteger fail for you? As using that library would be the the most easy-to-code solution here?

Comment: @GhostCat I got tle for half of the test cases

Comment: You are repeating what you already said. Tle means? But thinking about it : you are correct - you should focus on getting the modulo solution to work. It is always more efficient to make computations with smaller numbers.

Comment: @GhostCat tle means time limit exceeded...when i'm calculating with BigInteger i guess it is adding a lot more time complexity to the program

Answer (score 0):

You have added an extra zero the value of mod, it should be 1000000011.
Hope this will solve it

Comment: Share the link to the problem